# LDAP Credential Error when connect from thirty party software

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I am connecting to LDAP Server from a thirty party software. There are 2 users I use to login (user_a, user_b)

However, when I use these accounts to login, there are 2 different results:

In a thirty party software:
When I use user_a to login, everything is fine, the directory can be shown.
When I use user_b to login, I cannot query accounts, it say that "the credential is incorrect".

In ADExplore:
Both user_a and user_b can successfully login and show the directory.

Is there any settings cause these result? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Softerra LDAP Browser 4.5 and come up with below approach
 1. Login with that user (eg. user_a/user_b  in your case).
 2. Configure that third-party application to use current users credentials.